# How can I set ui-panelgrid-cell padding for a specific p:panelGrid?

Tags: css, primefaces

This is my page structure:

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <p:row>
        <p:column>
            <p:panelGrid id="innerPg_1">
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:panelGrid id="innerPg_2">
        </p:column>
    </p:row>
</p:panelGrid>
```

I would like to override the *padding* attribute on the *ui-panelgrid-cell* class, **only** for the panelGrid with id="innerPg_1", by making my own css rule.
How can I do that?

Tried with the following rule:

```
 #innerPg_1 .ui-panelgrid-cell {
     padding: 1px 1px !important;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Shouldn't it be a wrong rule?
The produced html part is:

```
<td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
    <tabled id="formId:innerPg_1"class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget role="grid">
```

Comment: Have you tried to add in your css file the following: `#innerPg_1 .ui-panelgrid-cell { property: xxx !important}` ? I'm not sure if `!important` is needed

Answer (score 0):

Well, the id of the component in the produced html isn't `innerPg_1`, it is `formId:innerPg_1`.

So, in your css you should use the following rule: `#formId\:innerPg_1 .ui-panelgrid-cell {...}`. (Don't forget the slash!!)

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, but at first, try just to change the `background-color`, just to check if the rule is being overrided

Also, using `styleClass` instead of `id` might be a better option, so you could reuse it for another panelGrid